# Ruby on rails project to maven build? creating pom.xml for the ROR project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, maven-3

I want to convert a simple ruby on rails project to maven is there any library that does the gem to pom.xml conversion?
Any pointers on how to do this is appreciated?

Comment: I don't understand. RoR is a framework for writing webapps while Maven is a build system. Are you wanting to convert a Ruby project to Java????

Comment: I want to convert the gemfile to pom.xml since all my projects are built through jenkins that takes pom.xml to build and deploy the projects

Comment: @ Todd R Currently I use jruby -s warble to compile and archive the project in war. instead of this if I get a pom file I can use Jenkins to do this automatically

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  Could you please edit your question to include the additional information you've added in comments, and any other information someone might need?  The question should stand alone, without someone needing to read the comments.

Comment: Ruby on Rails projects are typically **not** packaged into gems. And you should have made it clear that you're talking about a Ruby on Rails project built with JRuby, not MRI. That makes a big difference.